# Passing collection via asmx

Tags: c#, web-services, collections

I have a list of pairs (CarType(Enum), code(string)). Unfortunately in this collection codes are not unique.

```
Van,C1
Van,C2
Pickup,C1
```

How to pass this collection via asmx webservice.

Now I have KeyValuePair[] as parametr in webMethod

```
[webmethod]
public void DestroyCars(KeyValuePair<string, CarType>[] cars)
{
//implementation.
}
```

But when I update my webreference(not servicereference) and put instance of KeyValuePair[] in

```
service.DestroyCars(someinstance of KeyValuePair<string, CarType>[])
```

I get exception, because I must there KeyPairValuOfStringCarType.

Why is that and how to fix it ?

To be more clear:

I want to pass multidimension collection through webservice.

I create

[webmethod]
    public void DestroyCars(KeyValuePair[] cars)
    {
    //implementation.
    }

I update webreference of my application.

When I want to call this webmethod from my application with new instance of KeyValuePair[]  I get error that this parameter is not assignable to parameter type of my webmethod.

Intellisense tells me that type of this parameter is KeyPairValuOfStringCarType with is not a true.

I check type of this type in net.reflector and I see that is a string.

I know there is no sense. This is way I ask for help :/

Comment: Could you share exception message with us?

Comment: Sorry, not exception. I mean error.

Comment: Could you share the relevant information with us *irrespective* of whether it is an exception, and error, or something else? — Also, what does “because I must there KeyPairValuOfStringAndCarType” mean?

Comment: Thanks intellisense I know, that parameter of my webmethod is KeyPairValuOfStringAndCarType. I can create instance of this type at my client side. Error is "parameter type "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, CarType>[]"  is not assignable to parameter type mywebservicenamespace.KeyPairValuOfStringCarType

Comment: KeyPairValuOfStringAndCarType is NOT equivelant to KeyPairValuOfStringCarType

Comment: I corrected this is this examle. KeyPairValuOfStringCarType is this class created by webservice. KeyPairValuOfStringAndCarType  doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're encountering this error:

> "parameter type "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[]" is not assignable to parameter type mywebservicenamespace.KeyPairValuOfStringCarType

Is because when asp.net creates the web-service proxy (the web service reference) for you, it "duplicates" any custom types that your web service exposes, in this instance `KeyValuePair<string, CarType>` gets converted to `KeyValuePairOfStringCarType`  in the proxy, so that there's a way for you to pass these into the web service.

What you need to do to call your webservice is (this worked for me, in Visual Studio 2008, targeting an `asmx` web service):

```
// Create a new CarKeyValuePair in your web service project
public struct CarKeyValuePair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public CarType CarType { get; set; }
}

// Change your web method to use this instead of KeyValuePair
[WebMethod]
public void DestroyCars(CarKeyValuePair[] cars)
{
    // Implementation here
}
```

You can then update your web service reference and write something similar to the following in the code that calls your web service:

```
service.DestroyCars(new CarKeyValuePair[] { new CarKeyValuePair() { CarType = CarType.Pickup, Key = "C1" } });

// or

var cars = new List<CarKeyValuePair>();
var car = new CarKeyValuePair();
car.CarType = CarType.Pickup;
car.Key = "C1";
cars.Add(car);
service.DestroyCars(cars.ToArray());
```

Comment: @phenevo, not a problem =) As I suspect you already know, given your mention of *webreference(not servicereference)*, life becomes a *lot* easier if you move to a service reference and a shared type assembly as types get shared more readily, that's my experience with WCF based services anyway, not sure what difference it makes for asmx ones =)